# ImportError: No module named inspect

Tags: python, windows-10, conda, inspect, renderdoc

I am using renderdocui interactive python shell to import inspect but I get this error:

```
>> import inspect
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named inspect
```

I have installed python using Ananconda in Windows 10.

```
C:\Users\mona>ananconda search -t conda inspect
'ananconda' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\mona>conda install inspect
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: .


PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: '' Package missing in current win-64 channels:
  - inspect

You can search for packages on anaconda.org with

    anaconda search -t conda inspect
```

How should I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Do you by any chance have a file called inspect.py in your local directory or search path? It's possible Python is finding that and erroneously trying to import it instead of the actual module.

Comment: What happens if you try this line in the shell: import sys; print('\n'.join(sys.path) )   Or if that one doesn't work, try this one: import sys; print '\n'.join(sys.path)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are mis-typing `Anaconda` in your examples within your question.

```
C:\Users\mona>ananconda search -t conda inspect
```

should read:

```
C:\Users\mona>anaconda search -t conda inspect
```

It's probable that you need to tell renderdocui how to find your Python interpreter. On Windows, you path is probably along the lines of:

```
C:\Users\Jane Smith\anaconda\bin\python
```

I can't find much if any documentation on renderdocui, but if you have any documentation, it should direct you to where you set the path. Is there a settings panel or file?

To answer the second half of your question, you won't be able to install inspect independently using conda, as inspect is a Python builtin module.

Comment: then how do you install it? I get the same error when importing os module. it says `ImportError: No module named os`

Comment: Did you try this yet?: import sys; print('\n'.join(sys.path) )

Comment: And it shouldn't be something you install. It is a builtin module, which means that unless something is very non-standard and perhaps broken, it should simply be there.